# Inheritence trying to make a program

Tags: java

```
class Base1 {
    int x=50;
}

class Child extends Base1{
    int x=20;
    void show() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c1=new Child();
        c1.show();
    }
}
```

Hi I am new to java programming and while trying to run the above code in Netbeans I got an error

> Error: Main method not found in class base1.Base1, please define the main method as:
>          `public static void main(String[] args)`

please give the solution

Comment: "_please give the solution_" Please learn Java.

Comment: Please go to [The Java Tutorials: **Learning the Java Language**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class with the `main` method needs to be `public`.

```
public class Child extends Base1
```

Comment: You should have only one `public` class in the file and it should be with the same name as the file it's contained.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple classes in 1 classfile, if these are inner classes then you need to put the public static void main(...) in the outer class.